# Weird regex issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using Javascript to validate a pattern and i'm basically looking to just allow alphanumeric values and punctuations. Strangely, when I enter a ( or a ) immediately followed by something it fails but if I give it a space it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).on('blur', '#comment', function () {
      var rgx = /[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!"']$/;
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (!rgx.test(value) == true){
          $("#comment").focus();
          $("#commentError").val("Please use only alphabets, numbers and punctuations");
      }else{
        $("#commentError").val("");
      }
  });
```

Test Cases:

Passes for

```
Input: ( a
```

Fails for

```
Input: (a
```

Comment: Passes for both here. Could you include a complete, interactive example using the snippet feature, please? Also, if by “just” you mean in the entire string, you’ll need to anchor it to the start and allow multiple characters, so `/^[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!"']+$/`. Or for a negative test, `/[^\w .,!"']/`.

Comment: Added the full code block

Answer (score 1):

Your current pattern is only checking the last character in the string.

You will need to have a pattern that checks the entire string.  This is accomplished by using the `^` and `$` anchors and using a one or more quantifier `*` (assuming commenting is optional).

Your regex pattern can be:

`/^[\w .,!"']*$/` or `/^[A-Z0-9 _.,!"']*$/i` or `/^[u20-u22u27u2Cu2Eu30-u39u41-u5Au5F]*$/i`

The first is most brief (my preference), the second is probably most readable, and the third is using [unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/) and is the hardest to comprehend.  All will be fast, so speed isn't really a criteria.

Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mickmackusa/3wj25qdf/) with some refinements and commented advice.

HTML:

```
<input id="comment" name="comment" value="( a">
<i> press tab to trigger validation</i><br>
<input id="commentError" value="Comment Limit: 25. Use only letters, numbers, and  punctuation.">

<!-- I have added "?" to your regex pattern because it seems permissible. -->
<!-- Invalid values: "(a", "( a", "12345678901234567890123456" -->
<!-- Valid values: "", "Hello World", "l0ts, "of go.od' st_uff!?" -->

<!-- Additional advice: if you are storing the input value in a database table,
     you should limit the field length to what the table column can hold.
     If, per se, you are saving as VARCHAR(255), then set the #comment field limit
     as 255 so that the value isn't truncated during saving. -->
```

CSS:

```
#comment{
    width:200px;
}
#commentError{
    display:none;
    width:400px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('blur','#comment',function(){
    // no variable declaration needed
    if(/^[\w .,!"'?]{0,25}$/.test($(this).val())){  // contains only valid chars w/ limit
        $("#commentError").hide();
    }else{
        $("#comment").focus();  // disallows focus on any other field
        $("#commentError").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to solve your problem- there are a few differences but you should be able to just copy-paste it into your code.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pg792z79/

```
<script>
    var str = "apples" // <-- this is your input string
    var patt = new RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!"\'/$]*');
    if(patt.test(str)) {
        //success
        $("#commentError").val("");
    } else {
        //error - did not match regex
        $("#comment").focus();
        $("#commentError").val("Please use only alphabets, numbers and punctuations");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This regex pattern will ALWAYS give a positive response because the pattern  is satisfied by zero or more of the valid characters in the range, anywhere in the string.

Answer (score -1):

`/^[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!"']$/g`;   That's it.

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation.